# Regex do not match if any of the comma separated Email addresses contain @gym-kk.com

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a scenario: Regex do not match if any of the comma separated Email addresses contain @gym-kk.com.

`^[\w.+\-]+@gym-kk\.com$`

```
^([\w+-.%]+@[\w-.]+\.[A-Za-z]+)(; ?[\w+-.%]+@gym-kk+\.[A-Za-z]+)*$
```

The string that I have is jerry@yahoo.com; jim@gmail.com; cram@gym-kk.com

I tried different regex expressions but in all cases if the string contains just one @gym-kk.com address there is a match.

Answer (score 0):

So, you basically want to fail string if it contains @gym-kk.com?
If so `@gym-kk\.com($|;)` will do.